# Como mudar o http accept language no Firefox Developer Edition?

Tags: navegador-de-internet, http-headers

Estou desenvolvendo um site que deverá funcionar para português e inglês - de preferência automaticamente. Pelo php eu já pego o HTTP-ACCEPT-LANGUAGE, e preciso agora começar a testar o código que irá direcionar o conteúdo conforme a linguagem que o navegador informou.

Para testes, eu uso o Safari que (aparentemente) não tem como mudar o header na parte da linguagem. O Firefox Developer Edition também não, mas tem dois add-ons: O Quick Accept-Language Switcher e o Quick Locale Switcher. Ambos eu testei no meu localhost mas o php pega sempre o mesmo header (com o código pt) não importando a linguagem que eu selecione ou o código que eu insira (no caso do Quick Accept-Language).

Preciso um desses dois navegadores faça de conta que é gringo! Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize addons que faça alteração da headers.

https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/modify-headers/

Esse é um exemplo.

No chrome tem melhores addons para fazer isso, sugiro para desenvolvimento utilizar ele.

Comment: Esse funcionou, e é mais completo que os anteriores porque me permitirá mudar outras variáveis se eu precisar. Eu já uso o Safari, Firefox e o Opera (para simular o smartphone), não sei se vou incluir mais o Chrome, mas obrigado pela dica.